# tabs color different

Tags: jquery, css, colors

I want to give each tab a different color, but how do i do this? 
ive tried things like give each link or ul a class, but that didn't work.
i know the anwser is probertly simple but i can't work out what is should be 
here are the codes ive used

this is my css

```
<style>
.tabs li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
}

.tabs a {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#999;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:172px;
    height:30px;
}

.tabs a.active {
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
}
.inhoud {
    padding:18px;
    width:600px;
    padding-top:20px;
    width:965px;
    height:870px;
}
.tabstitel{
    padding:10px;
    width:120px;
    background:#099;
}
</style>
```

and this is in my body

```
<ul class='tabs'>
            <li class="tab1"><a class="tabstitel" href='#tab1'>titel</a></li>
            <li class="tab1"><a class="tabstitel" href='#tab2'>titel</a></li>
            <li class="tab1"><a class="tabstitel" href='#tab3'>titel</a></li>
            <li class="tab1"><a class="tabstitel" href='#tab4'>titel </a></li>
            <li class="tab1"><a class="tabstitel" href='#tab5'>titel</a></li>
```

and the script

```
$('ul.tabs').each(function () {
  var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
  $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
  $active.addClass('active');
  $content = $($active.attr('href'));
  $links.not($active).each(function () {
    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
  });
  $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $content.hide();
    $active = $(this);
    $content = $($(this).attr('href'));
    $active.addClass('active');
    $content.show();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: In your javaScript, at the top, you can just write .tabs instead of ul.tabs. You want to say "style .tabs" not "style any ul with the class of tabs." In the CSS you can just put .active instead of .tabs a.active. you want to say, "style .active" not " style any link with class of active that is in an element with a class of .tabs" --

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#tab1{background-color:red}
#tab2{background-color:green}
#tab3{background-color:blue}
#tab4{background-color:yellow}
#tab5{background-color:purple}
```

or something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

This is stripped down: [HERE is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/J7mc6/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class='tabs'>
    <li class="tab1"><a href="?">titel</a></li>
    <li class="tab2"><a href="?">titel</a></li>
    <li class="tab3"><a href="?">titel</a></li>
    <li class="tab4"><a href="?">titel</a></li>
    <li class="tab5"><a href="?">titel</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.tabs {
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none; /* this is the list... */

    /* this is just to dempnstrate how the ul should contain the elements */
}

.tabs li {
    float: left;
}

.tabs a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em 2em;

    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    margin-right: 1em;
}



.tab1 a {
    background-color: orange;
}

    .tab1 a:hover { /* example :hover */        
    background-color: #f06;
    }

    .tab1 a:active { /* example :active */        
    background-color: #000;
    }

.tab2 a {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.tab3 a {
    background-color: lime;
}

.tab4 a {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.tab5 a {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

I don't really fully understand this yet, but giving a  a class and then calling it out in your CSS like `a.myclass { }` is, I guess, too specific and heavy for the browser and generally a no no. So as far as I can tell you want to call them out `.list-item-class a { }` - more specifically - if you want to future proof for a possible second tier of ul in your list, you can use > like... `.list-class > .list-item-class > a { }`

There is a great resource [HERE on CSS Selectors](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/).  see #8 on the list.

Comment: @user2080695 did you figure it out? Were you trying to add a class to the active link? a different class for each? I'm confused by your script.